# Need code to copy and paste specific values from selected rows on a table on a worksheet to cells within a table on another

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for vba code to copy and paste certain column values from selected rows on a table in to fields on another table.

I have tried the following code which is successfully transferring the data as I require but I would prefer to use the table headers than the column references and it is copying some formulas and formatting when I just want the values.

I am essentially looking to populate a form template with selected rows data:

```
  Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONSIGNMENT REGISTER")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEFFERED WORK FORM")

    Dim DestRow As Long
    DestRow = 9

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -16).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "B")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -18).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "C")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -20).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "D")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -19).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "E")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -17).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "F")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -15).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "G")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -14).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "H")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -13).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "I")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -12).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "J")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -10).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "K")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -11).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "L")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -21).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "M")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -1).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "N")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -2).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "O")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -5).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "P")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -4).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "Q")
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -3).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "R")
        DestRow = DestRow + Rng.Rows.Count
    Next Rng

End Sub
```

I have included a column "Highlight" on the first table for the user to select the rows and a command button to use to create the form.

I will combine it with a module to unhide the form template, paste this data, copy the template to a new tab in a new workbook (to save individually), set the template back to blank and hide again...

unless there is a much simpler way of doing what I require?

Answer (score 0):

To only copy the Value (without formatting, formulas and the rest ...) of your cell of interest:

instead of this:

```
Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -16).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "B")
```

you could try simply this:

```
wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "B").Value = Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -16).Value
```

... and of course repeating this on all the other lines...

This is about your first question....

About the rest:

Without seeing what you are doing exactly, I am not sure I can comment if there is a simpler way of picking the data and filling the template.

You could ask that in a separate question with screenshots added.